# How come permission is not required to access directory of email addresses in android?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have the following code below that reveals me the entire email list of a Android phone.

```
    val emailPickerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(emailPickerIntent, REQUEST_CONTACTS_CODE)
```

I understand that Android requires a user to explicitly give permission if we want to read/write to Contacts. However, in this case it seems that no permission needs to be given for the email list. Did google decide emails were not considered sensitive information?

Comment: You don't get the email list. The system displays that list. You only get the email that the user picked. So by picking an email the user obviously declared intent to tell you that specific email; no extra permissions required.

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT , it totally makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> reveals me the entire email list of a Android phone

No, it reveals *to the user* the entire email list. Your application code does not have access to the list.

If the user picks a contact, the `Uri` delivered to you (via `onActivityResult()` for `REQUEST_CONTACTS_CODE` in your case) will allow you to get details of that individual contact. The user, by selecting the contact, is granting you short-term access to that one contact, and only that one contact.

> Did google decide emails were not considered sensitive information?

They do. That's why you need `READ_CONTACTS` to be able to query the `ContactsContract` provider directly. If the user is involved in the contact selection, though, that permission is not needed for whatever contact the user selects.